# Coloring a $9\times9$ Board

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, chessboard

Consider a $9 \times 9$ board, and we want to paint each of the $81$ squares either white or black. There are $64$ $2\times2$ squares within the $9\times9$ board, and there are $16$ different $2\times2$ "paintings" (for example, $\begin{pmatrix} W&B\\B&W\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} B&B\\B&W\end{pmatrix}$, etc.).

**Question:** By Pigeonhole Principle, at least one of the $16$ $2\times2$ paintings must appear at least $\frac{64}{16} = 4$ times. Is there, however, a realization that uses **every** $2\times2$ painting **exactly** $4$ times?

**Best Attempt:** I have the following $9\times9$ masterpiece, which uses $14$ $2\times2$ paintings exactly 4 times but uses $\begin{pmatrix} B&B\\B&W\end{pmatrix}$ $5$ times and $\begin{pmatrix} W&B\\B&B\end{pmatrix}$ only $3$ times. See here:

[image: 9by9nearmiss]

Comment: Nice combinatorical problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tile the plane with copies of the $4\times4$ pattern

$$\pmatrix{0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\1&0&1&1\\0&1&1&1}$$

(using, say $0$ for Black and $1$ for White).  Then any $9\times9$ subarray will contain the $16$ different $2\times2$ patterns exactly $4$ times.

The essential idea here is to identify opposite edges of the $4\times4$ array, making a torus out of the square.  It's a bit laborious, but not all that hard, to check that the $16$ different $2\times2$ patterns occur exactly once.  Four copies of it, therefore, again with toroidal identification of edges, contain the $16$ patterns $4$ times each.  Buffering four copies with an extra row and column simply makes the toroidal identification explicit.

Remark:  Peter's $9\times9$ solution is not of this "toroidal-based" form.

Comment: Perfect generalization!

Comment: There are 32 "toroidal" solutions, but they are all reducible to the one in this excellent answer by flips and rotations of the arrays, and rotations of the rows or columns.

Comment: That's really exceptional.

Answer (score 3):

```
[0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]

[1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1]

[1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]

[1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0]

[0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]

[1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]

[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]

[1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]

[0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0]
```

should be a coloring satisfying the condition! Can someone verify it ?

Comment: That's really awesome. I figured it must be possible!

Comment: PARI/GP is also great for combinatorical problems! And I only produced random arrangements and found a solution in reasonable time.